# How can I encode reserved XML characters in actionscript?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, encode, web-services

I am writing a business app in Flex that uses web services to communicate with a middle tier.  The web services accept and return messages in XML format.  In many cases, I need to be able to allow the user to type something like the following into a field in the app, which in turn will be added as an element in an XML payload bound for a SOAP web service (without the quotes):

"account balance < 1000"

The Flex parser chokes when trying to serialize an element with this in the Text node (e.g., account balance < 1000.  So I need some way to encode the "<" to "<" prior to doing the XML serialization.  In addition, I would prefer a generic way to do this, such as with an attribute on the service declaration, since I have over 40 services that must support this kind of input.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the escape and unescape functions.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary199.html

Comment: That works okay, however, encoding the string results in the input being several times longer than the original string.  The service I am calling has a maxlength constraint on the element in question and apparently the encoded string is not being decoded before evaluating the constraint.  So now I am getting a schema violation error.

Comment: Do you have control over the service?

If you do, then you need to unescape the string as the first step in the service.

If not, then I think you're out of luck.  SOAP web services' message container is XML.  Your message can't contain anything that confuses the XML Parser.  Either you remove the special characters (<, >, & etc.) or you change them and then change them back on the server.  This is the standard practice.

Comment: Would the answer be any different if I had generated an ActionScript proxy for the web service from the WSDL?  As it is, I am just creating an XML document that happens to correspond to the schema that describes the web service contract.  (There's a long, long story as to why I'm doing it this way.)  Seems like any reasonable web service framework would handle the encoding/decoding of reserved XML characters automatigically....

Comment: That should be easy enough to test.